# Select rows containing the group-wise maximum of a column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Say I've got a table named Item, which contains items with a price, set on a certain date.

**Item**

```
id | date       | price
---+------------+------
1  | 2014-01-01 | 1.09
1  | 2014-03-15 | 1.19
2  | 2014-04-02 | 2.75
1  | 2014-07-28 | 0.99
2  | 2014-08-07 | 2.35
3  | 2014-10-21 | 3.90
```

Now I'd like to select the current price per item (last record for each item):

```
WITH lastChange AS (
    SELECT id, MAX(date) date
    FROM Item
    GROUP BY id
)

SELECT Item.id, Item.price
FROM Item
JOIN lastChange ON Item.id = lastChange.id AND Item.date = lastChange.date
```

Giving:

```
id | price
---+------
1  | 0.99
2  | 2.35
3  | 3.90
```

I'm wondering whether there is a better way to make this selection.

Comment: What if you have two rows with the same id and date but different prices?

Comment: Let's say that doesn't happen. This is a simplified example. I could as well add times including milliseconds but that doesn't make the question more clear I guess.

Comment: The basic question is clear enough: "How do I select whole rows containing the group-wise maximum of one column".  Think carefully about how to handle a situation with more than one latest-price in one group.  If you don't want it to ever happen, use a UNIQUE constraint on the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Windowing functions**

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT *
   ,MAX(date) OVER(PARTITION BY id) max_date_by_id
  FROM Item
)
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE date = max_date_by_id
```

**Cross apply**

```
SELECT *
FROM Item t
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT MAX(date) max_date_by_id
  FROM Item
  WHERE id = t.id
)
WHERE date = max_date_by_id
```

Comment: I'm favoring the windowing functions over my own solution and the cross apply, since this gives more options in case the query become more complex, like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8d4c/1/0